# Archiving error: no matching architecture

Tags: xcode, git, alamofire

I'm building a watchOS app for an existing iOS app. I built the watch app in a different branch and then merged it into the main branch once I had it working. There were some conflicts and a couple of errors that I had to fix, but now I am able to run the app in the simulator and on actual hardware. The problem is that when I try to archive it to submit to the app store I get this error.

> fatal error: codesign_allocate: input file: /Users/Erik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EyeGames-bmfkraaipqcwtzbierlxfqsmdysn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ParseStarterProject/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire does not contain a matching architecture for specified '-a armv7k 20800' option

I have tried updating to the latest version of Alamofire, clearing the derived data, and cleaning the project, but all without any luck. I haven't been able to find any similar errors on Stack Overflow either, which worries me.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: same problem here. are you using cocoapods as well? i thought that might be the issue.

Comment: No, I just imported the Alamofire project into my project as a subproject and added it as an embedded framework. If I ever find a solution I'll make sure to post it here.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution so I wound up having to redo everything using the built in NSURLSession. Constructing the URLs manually was a big pain, but it was the only work around I could find.